# Dialog theme crashes application

Tags: android

I wanted to create some kind of window with some text information. After clicking a button an intent is started to open a new class.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

When I add this in AndroidManifest.xml my application crashes after clicking the button.

The .xml file of opened class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_infotext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/info_text"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: So you're starting a new Activity using an Intent, you're setting the theme for the new Activity in the manifest, the theme you're using is for a dialog. I don't think you can do this. Do you know how to show a dialog? Is that your intention?

Comment: Well, I am following a book. Tried something else; android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" and it works like intended. A dialog window appears. So it's fine actually. But why wouldn't the exact theme work?

Answer (score 0):

`Theme.Dialog` is only designed to be used for a `Dialog`. If you want to apply this theme to a `Dialog`, you can easily create a separate theme for your `Dialog`:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</style>
```

Then simply use that theme whenever you create a new `Dialog`; we will use an `AlertDialog` for example's sake:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogTheme));
```

Comment: what is the point of `DialogTheme` ? why not use `Theme.Dialog` directly?

Comment: You are correct. I always just do it like the example above should I wish to add further customization in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The Theme.Dialog is meant only for Dialogs displayed in your app not for your entire application. Try this:

In AndroidManifest.xml update to this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Then in styles.xml add as below:

```
<style name="mydialogstyle" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then in your dialogs set the style using this:

```
    setStyle(R.style.mydialogstyle, 0);
```